# Mount parent component in child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mount

I have two files named `Recursive.vue` and `Value.vue`.

In the first instance `Recursive` is the parent. Mounting `Recursive` in `Recursive` goes great, same for mounting `Value` in `Recursive` and after that `Value` in `Value`.

But when I've mounted `Value` in `Recursive` and trying to mount `Recursive` in `Value` after that I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
(found in component <recursive>)
```

How can I make my problem work?

This is what my files are looking like:

**Recursive**

```
<template>
  <div class="recursive">
    <h1 @click="toggle">{{comps}}</h1>
    <div v-if="isEven">
      Hello
      <value :comps="comps"></value>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Value from './Value.vue'

export default {
  name: 'recursive',
  components: {
    Value
  },
  props: {
    comps: Number
  },
  computed: {
    isEven () {
      return this.comps % 2 == 0;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle () {
      this.comps++;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Value**

```
<template>
  <div class="value">
    <h1 @click="toggle">{{comps}}</h1>
    <div v-if="isEven">
      <recursive :comps="comps"></recursive>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Recursive from './Recursive.vue'

export default {
  name: 'value',
  components: {
    Recursive
  },
  props: {
    comps: Number
  },
  computed: {
    isEven () {
      return this.comps % 2 == 0;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle () {
      this.comps++;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Mounter**

```
<template>
  <div class="mounter">
    <h1>HI</h1>
    <recursive :comps="comps"></recursive>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Recursive from './Recursive'

export default {
  name: 'mounter',
  components: {
    Recursive
  },
  data () {
    return {
      comps: 0
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add the code or create a fiddle of it?

Comment: @saurabh I added my code, making a fiddle would be hard because it contains multiple files.

Comment: Could we see code where you are mounting vue instance to the element in DOM ?

Comment: @BelminBedak this is my literal code. There is only one more file that just mounts Recursive at the start.

Comment: Yes, could you please post it here.

Comment: @BelminBedak I've added the code of the mounter file

Comment: Okay, I see you didn't actually mount your app to element in the DOM.So in your static file (index.html, blade or whatever) you have to define div element with unique id and then mount it to vue instance `const app = new Vue({
 render: (h) => h(Mounter)
}).$mount('#app')` don't forget to import Mounter component.

Comment: @BelminBedak this is automatically done if you use vue-cli. Here you have a main.js file which does what you said. It's not the problem I get to see nothing on my screen, I just don't get to see the content from Recursive inside the Value file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem before. The only way out was declaring the component as "global", because importing it in the component which actually required it never worked.

```
new Vue({
...
})

Vue.component('recursive', require('./Recursive'))
```

Then you can just use without importing:

```
// Mounted
<template>
  <div class="mounter">
    <h1>HI</h1>
    <recursive :comps="comps"></recursive>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'mounter',
  data () {
    return {
      comps: 0
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Pretty much!  Thanks!